# Kendo Grid: Group by first element in a list

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid

So I'm working with a Kendo Grid and how it's headers are grouped. One option that I have working currently is for the Grid to grab my list and sort group by checking every element in that list. So I get something like:

> ->Roles:
>
> ->Roles: Tester, Manager, Team Lead
>
> ->Roles: Tester
>
> ->Roles: CEO, Tester
>
> ->Roles: Team Lead, CEO

(you get the idea). This is because "Roles" in my database model are in a list (since a person can have many roles) and the Kendo Grid is comparing every element in that list. However, I want it to group by just the first element in each person's list so I instead get something like:

> ->Roles: Tester
>
> ->Roles: Manager
>
> ->Roles: Team Lead
>
> ->Roles:
>
> ->Roles: CEO

etc. Does anyone know how to do this? Currently I am doing

```
group: {
                field: "RoleName",
                aggregates: [
                    { field: "ResourceName", aggregate: "count" },
                    { field: "OrganizationName", aggregate: "count" }
                ]
            },
```

And I assume that I want to be doing something more along the lines of:

```
group: {
                field: "RoleName.get(0)",
                aggregates: [
                    { field: "ResourceName", aggregate: "count" },
                    { field: "OrganizationName", aggregate: "count" }
                ]
            },
```

However, I'm not familiar enough with Kendo Grid to know the syntax to do this correctly. Thanks in advance for all help!

Edit: I should add that because many of the people that will be using this still need IE8 support, I am using Kendo Grid imports from /2012.2.710 instead of the latest update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit My Answer assumes the user loads the data outside the function and doesn't hard code in the data.

Try using the parse function in schema,

I'll just add to what you should have in your project already, for example:

```js
$('.grid').kendoGrid({
  dataSource: {
    schema: {
      parse: function(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          data[i].firstWord = data[i].name.split(' ')[0];
        }
        return data;
      }
    }
    group: {
      field: "firstWord"
    }
  },
  columns: [{
    field: "name"
  }, {
    field: "firstWord",
    hidden: true,
    groupHeaderTemplate: "#=value#"
  }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a fix over [Ryan Hoyle answer's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30716569/3078890):

```js
var grid = $('#grid').kendoGrid({
  dataSource: {
    data: [{
      name: 'Hello world'
    }, {
      name: 'Hello John Doe'
    }, {
      name: 'Hello Jane Doe'
    }, {
      name: 'Bye Jane Doe'
    }, {
      name: 'Bye World'
    }],
    schema: {
      parse: function(data) {
        data.forEach(d => d.firstWord = d.name.split(' ')[0]);
        return data;
      }
    },
    group: {
      field: "firstWord"
    }
  },
  columns: [{
    field: "name"
  }, {
    field: "firstWord",
    hidden: true,
    groupHeaderTemplate: "#=value#"
  }]
}).data().kendoGrid;
```

```html
<link href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div id="grid"></div>
```